# What does the word "matted" mean?

Tags: word-usage

I've just moved to London with my parents and I'm not very confident with my English language knowledge. I need to write an essay for my English classes on the topic "home decorations". We have a list of words that I need to use in the text but I don't know what "matted" means. Could anyone explain?

Comment: You need to add context.  If I say "the matted entryway," then I'm describing an entryway that is adorned with a small rug.  If I say "the matted carpet," then I'm describing worn carpet whose woven fibers are crushed down and no longer spring back up.

Comment: There are several different meanings for the word.

Comment: Those who VTC..a casual look-up for "matted" is unhelpful.

Comment: @Cascabel - That's nice. The OP should include that in their question then.

Comment: What's wrong with the definitions at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matted, https://www.lexico.com/definition/matted, etc.?

Comment: The word has many meanings and senses. But one adjectival sense is used for anything interwoven, tangled or sticky. This could be anything from a woven rush mat, to someone's hair after it had had a tub of glue poured into is.

Comment: There's also matted art. I agree, context is needed.

Comment: As home decoration, matted art is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of home decorations, it likely refers to "[mat board or matte board](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mat%20board)", a heavy fiberboard frame under the glass, in a picture frame.

[Representative search on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=large%20matted%20frames&gclid=Cj0KCQjww7HsBRDkARIsAARsIT6SZmQroL5DPEYFWQiqRMmcvSzwFsN6dVmswfDbwczw7AiVeoERtboaAtEgEALw_wcB&hvadid=318573636902&hvdev=t&hvlocphy=9007324&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t2&hvqmt=b&hvrand=12788717992608517407&hvtargid=kwd-301927090057&hydadcr=14506_10191270&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_5mf2bmdj2c_b)

Comment: This is right, you just need to provide more context. "Matted" refers to prints which are mounted on matte board.

Comment: but without context, it could be, as comments indicate, something different.

Comment: Not in the UK it doesn't. And OP has just moved to London.

Answer (score 0):

It, of course, depends on context.

You may use it in the following meaning in your work: "Matted" is frequently used to describe pictures or artworks that are covered with mats - a piece of cardboard that comes with the picture frames as a decorative element.

F.e. check out this website to see how it looks: https://framedandmatted.com/. You can also find some interesting ideas for your essay there.

Comment: As the OP is in London, this may not be the usage intended, as picture mats are called _mounts_ in British English.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing) . Certainly this usage of the word was completely unknown to me.